# Not able to see Resolve client jars in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying for integrate one signal for android push notifications. After importing the package When I opened Assets > Play Services Resolver ...
There I did not have Android Resolver and Resolve Client Jars. Instead of that i have Assets > Play Services Resolver->Android Resolver 1.Settings
                                                       2.Resolve
                                                       3.Force Resolve.

I am following this document https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/unity-sdk-setup

Comment: What version of the Unity editor are you using? I think option 2. Resolve should work for you

Comment: I am using 2018..1.0f2. Yes m, I tried of option 2 but the device is not registering .

Comment: Go to File -> Build Settings -> Select Android and export your project as an Android Project. Then try selecting from Assets - > Play Services Resolver -> Android Resolver -> Resolve

Comment: Thanks for response @DarshanPania, My project is already in Android platform.

Comment: The play service resolver has received some updates in the last few months. It simplifies a lot of the process. Using (android) Force Resolve should automatically (re)import everything you need.